# Compute shaders in Kha

Tags: compute-shader, kha

I am reworking an old voxels module for an opensource game engine, and am unable to get the compute shaders to work;

I'm 100% sure the opacity is being written on in the preceding steps, because if I skip the compute shader steps, there is data that conetracing functions can handle.

Here is the link to the repo in case you want to help out: https://github.com/e2002e/armory voxelgi
But if you do need to test it, you need the whole SDK : https://github.com/e2002e/armsdk (needs a submodule update --init --recursive --remote)

The issue is not withing the shader itself, I'm creating two images : one for opacity, and another one that takes the opacity as input in the compute shader and use it together with light data to write on the final image.

Nothing happens, either the first image can't be read, or the final one can't be written on, or maybe the compute shader is not being run or wrongly parameterized.

There is an issue that might be related ; when using RGBA32 instead of RGBA64 for voxels there is no data. I'm not sure what's going on since Kha is a vast API and documentation is scarce.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually an issue with the programming interface which was solved by opening an issue.